# PHP image table from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've got a database that contains info on some images. The columns are id, name, description, location and visible.

I'm trying to have PHP read in the location column as an array `WHERE visible=1`, but it's not working. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

I know I should be using mysqli, before anyone points this out to me. I will do, once I've got this array syntax sorted out.

My code is below:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("shibby",$con);
$sql = "SELECT location from gallery WHERE visible=1";
$photos= mysql_query($sql,$con);
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
mysql_close($con);

$i = 0;
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $i = 0;
    if ($i < 3) {
        echo '<td><center><img src="'.$photo.'.jpg"></td>';
        $i++;
    } elseif ($i == 3) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What did you want to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: `$result` is not defined. Change `$photos= mysql_query($sql,$con);` to `$result= mysql_query($sql,$con);` and set the fetch method to `$photos`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. 
I get one image displayed. thats it.
When I echo $photos, i dont see a array, I see just the first item.

Comment: As a side note, the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated. You should transition to [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Have a look at [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) in the manual - it just fetches a row, not the whole resultset. Look at the examples on that page to see how to retrieve all results.

Comment: if you want to use `mysql_fetch_array` use it in a while loop so it will function as intended. Still, mysqli will be different so it's a waste of time messing with mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `print_r` from this line and replace this

`mysql_fetch_array($photos); // you had used wrong variable`

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined variable 'result'` (line 12)

Change

```
$photos= mysql_query($sql,$con);
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

with

```
$photos= mysql_query($sql,$con);
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($photos));
```

Comment: Incorrect: mysql_fetch_array only returns one row, not multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

Please do [NOT USE MYSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) methods on new projects!! Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (I prefer the latter as the first one is a PITA to get right)

If you really insist on correcting the existing code, fix the location retrieval as follows:

```
$result= mysql_query($sql,$con);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
   $photos[] = $row['location'];
}
```

mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_row only get one row of the results, not the complete set, hence the need for the loop in the above

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$photos= mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql,$con));
```

And remove the line:

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

And yes, use PDO or MySQLi :)

Comment: Incorrect: does not retrieve multiple rows as needed.